# Video partial content / range request on mobile / iOS Safari iPhone

Tags: ios, html5-video, mobile-safari

I'm trying to replicate a scroll-linked video as seen in this CodePen:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/32782-video-scroll-animation/

This approach works fine on Chrome / Edge / FF / Safari on Mac, iPad but not on iPhone. Previously, this demo used to work on iPhones (iOS Safari, or other browsers which all use iOS Safari under the hood anyways), but in recent few weeks neither my implementation nor this CodePen works.

Has there been any change recently to iOS Safari on iPhones to warrant this change? On Android mobile devices as well, it seems quite clunky, but it's perfectly fine on iPad / desktops.